# leap_year.javaにコンパイルエラーが出る

Tags: java

leap_year.java

```
class leap_year{
    int dim;
    int uruudosi(int yy);
    if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
        dim = 29; // うるう年
    else
        dim = 28;
    }
    return dim;
}
```

cmdでのエラー

```
leap_year.java:7: エラー: 型の開始が不正です
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: 型の開始が不正です
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
   ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: ')'がありません
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
    ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: ';'がありません
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
        ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: 型の開始が不正です
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
           ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: <identifier>がありません
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
            ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: ';'がありません
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
               ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: 型の開始が不正です
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
                  ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: ';'がありません
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
                         ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: <identifier>がありません
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
                                             ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: 型の開始が不正です
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
                                                ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: <identifier>がありません
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
                                                   ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: ';'がありません
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
                                                      ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: 型の開始が不正です
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
                                                        ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: <identifier>がありません
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
                                                         ^
leap_year.java:7: エラー: ';'がありません
if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
                                                          ^
leap_year.java:8: エラー: 型の開始が不正です
                dim = 29; // うるう年
                    ^
leap_year.java:8: エラー: <identifier>がありません
                dim = 29; // うるう年
                     ^
leap_year.java:9: エラー: 型の開始が不正です
            else
            ^
leap_year.java:9: エラー: ';'がありません
            else
                ^
leap_year.java:10: エラー: 型の開始が不正です
                dim = 28;
                    ^
leap_year.java:10: エラー: <identifier>がありません
                dim = 28;
                     ^
leap_year.java:12: エラー: class、interfaceまたはenumがありません
        return dim;
        ^
leap_year.java:13: エラー: class、interfaceまたはenumがありません
}
^
エラー24個
```

このコンパイルエラーをどう直したらいいかがわかっていないです。どのように修正したらいいでしょうか。

Comment: メソッドの中に書く必要があります。

Comment: そんなに簡単にメソッドをかけって言われましても、どこを直せばいいのか、教えて欲しいんですが。

Comment: この前の質問で`daysinmonth`ってメソッドがありますね。これは、年と月からその月の日数を返すメソッドですね。これと同じよう（なスタイル）に書けばいいのです。

Comment: なぜこの質問はDown Voteされているんでしょうか？ちょっとおかしくないですか？  
確かに、
・他の質問と実は関連しているがそれを示していない
・何を質問したいのか書かれていないという面はありますが  
理由もなしにDown Voteされてしまうのでは質問者がいなくなってしまいますよ

Comment: この質問、-4程度でいいと思いますが。。。私はUpVoteしときました。

Answer (score 1):

これを動くように改善するなら次のような感じでしょうか。

```
class leap_year{
    int dim;
    int uruudosi(int year){
    if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
        dim = 29; // うるう年
    }else{
        dim = 28;
    }
    return dim;
   }
}
```

インデントはぐちゃぐちゃですが、こうなりました。
更に改善するには、

```
public class leap_year{
    public static int uruudosi(int year){
//インスタンスを生成せずにアクセスできる
        int dim;//フィールドにする必要はない
        if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0){
                dim = 29; // うるう年
          }else{
                dim = 28;
        }
          return dim;
    }
 }
```

ですかね。

Answer (score 0):

とりあえず動かしてみました。  
dim？？？Java未経験者でしょうか？eclipseとか使ってちょ  
[これはリンク！Wandboxという便利なサイトで実動を確認したよ！！！](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vZo4IYF6EmKFOuCr)

この回答でよかったらベストアンサーにしてたもれ

```
class LeapYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(uruudoshi(2008));
    }

    private static int uruudoshi(int year) {

        int dim = 0;
        System.out.println("判定対象は:" + year);

        if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) {
            dim = 29; // うるう年
            System.out.println("うるう年っぽい");
        } else {
            dim = 28;
            System.out.println("うるう年じゃないっぽい");
        }

        return dim;
    }
}
```

Comment: [前回の質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/12196/8000)に書かれたコードを見ると、dim は days in month の略かなと…。

Answer (score 0):

うるう年判定については、ここスタックオーバーフローでも幾つか質問がでています。
そのなかの方法と、この質問にあったコードの方法の動作比較をしてみました。

```
// See http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12196/
//     http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12207/

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class LeapYear {

    // java のメソッドを利用したうるう年の判定

    static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        return calendar.isLeapYear(year);
    }

    // 自作のうるう年の判定
    static int uruudosi(int year) {
        int days2 = 28; // うるう年でないときの２月の日数
        if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
            days2 = 29; // うるう年のときの２月の日数
        }
        return days2;
    }

    static public void main(String args[]) {
        // 2 つのうるう年判定の結果をテストする。
        for (int i = 1900; i < 2100; i++) {
            boolean leap = isLeapYear(i);
            int days2 = uruudosi(i);
            if (leap != (days2 == 29)) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + i + ": leap=" + leap + ", day2 =" + days2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```